# android how to set arrayAdapter layout that prepared programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to use custom listview with an arrayadapter. I have a layout for this adapter.But I want to create layout of this adapter programmatically.Arrayadapter pass the id of this layout to its super. It doesnt accept layout. How can I pass the layout object instead of resourceId?

super(context, LayoutResourceId, ArrayList);

Comment: where are the LayoutResourceId and ArrayList defined?

Comment: use a BaseAdapter instead, you don't need to pass any id to super class

Comment: normally it takes LayoutResourceId from R.java that is id of layout and Arraylist is list of myObject. But now it isnot in R.java it prepared with programmatically

Comment: @Atrix1987 on baseAdapter in getView I use an inflater and its inflate method takes id again it doesnt accept layout.

Comment: @nrllh the inflater needs the ID of a layout to inflate...just like this constructor of the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: if you are creating layouts dynamically like  new RelativeLayout(context), you don't need to inflate layout xmls

Answer (score 1):

for the ArrayAdapter you might not need to extend it, just instantiate it and use it...use this constructor: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29)

```
new ArrayAdapter(context, layoutResourceId,arrayList);
```

Comment: I want to pass layout object not the layoutResourceId. on setContentview() method it takes id or view or view and layout. But arraydapter absolutely takes layoutResourceId

Comment: You can't do that, the layout object is instantiated (inflated) on demand by the adapter, that is the reason why we use adapters. It will not only create one view object (layout object) internally, but as many as necessary to build the UI...and it does it on-demand. Why don't you wanna pass the ID?

Comment: I am working on a sdk project. It java based on project not an android project.I have an activity class and I must create layouts programmatically

Comment: hummm...then you maybe can subclass this base class from your Sdk project and onthe actual Android project, the subclass would provide implementation for a method like: protected int getLayoutResId();

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible. Because ArrayAdapter has no default constructor. also u need to specify the structure of the view and also on which it should draw the view thats why arrayadapter takes layout id and context as one of its parameter

```
       ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) is the constructor of ArrayAdapter with least parameter.
```