# How to apply ArrayAdapter parameters as programatically made layout?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

For ArrayAdapter,

```
ArrayAdapter <String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(Context , resId , viewId , String[])
```

We need to have resId and viewId but how can i use Custom programmatically made Android Views ??
Is there any way so that i can apply programatically made layouts in this ArrayAdapter ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android how to set arrayAdapter layout that prepared programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518662/android-how-to-set-arrayadapter-layout-that-prepared-programmatically)

Comment: No , it don't @GregorRant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not quite get the question, hope this helps:

**How to get the view id**

If you programatically created a view and want to get its id, you need to call this:

```
view.setId(View.generateViewId());
int id = view.getId();
```

Same goes for Layouts (classes that extend `Viewgroup`), because they are views (`ViewGroup` extends `View`).

**Code example:**

```
layout.setId(View.generateViewId());
view.setId(View.generateViewId());
ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, layout.getId(), view.getId());
```

**How to apply an ArrayAdapter**

Every object that extends `AbsListView` has a `setAdapter()`-Method, in that you can pass an ArrayAdapter.